# How to set dom node's correct width with [ position : fixed ]?

Tags: html, css, width, fixed

I need a div fixed on the top of the page using `position : fixed`.

But if the browser's size is changed the div's width will changed because fixed node's parent is the screen not the parent DOM node.

How can I set `position : fixed` node's width corresponding to the parent node not full screen?

Comment: You can't do that with plain css. position fixed is always with respect to the document and never with respect to its parent element. You will have to use javascript to compute the width of the element you need and then apply it to the fixed element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make `position:fixed` relative to any parent. It's always the browsers window.

You can, however, make `position:absolute` relative to another object. With `margin` settings of `-x` or `-y` you can even make it hover over the original element's position, but still relative.

To make `position:fixed` or `absolute` relative to window size or parent size, respectively, use percentages:

```css
p {
  position:fixed;
  left:10%;
  right:10%;
  top:10%;
  bottom:10%;
  background-color:green;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```